# How many ways to build a 3-digit odd number (no repetition)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I searched and could only find an answer for the problem with repetition of the following question.

How many 3-digit odd numbers greater than 600 can be created using the digits 2,3,4,5,6, and 7? Repetition of digits is not allowed.

I found the correct answer, $20$, by creating a tree, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of counting this.

Comment: If it begins with $6$, then three choices for the last place and four for the middle, making $12$.  If it begins with $7$, then two choices for the last and four four the middle making $8$.  $12+8=20$.  Not sure if that's elegant, though.

Comment: It's more elegant than what I had :)  
How does that solution account for something like $653$, where you start with $6$, choose one of the remaining $5$, and then only have one option remaining?

Comment: It's covered.  You start with $6$, choose $3$ for the last digit, and then choose $5$ for the middle.

Comment: So if I were to give myself some sort of rule for solving these types of problems, would it make sense to say, "order your steps from most restrictive to least"? For instance, the middle digit has an effect on what I can choose for the units, but not the other way around, so start with units?

Comment: It's very hard to generalize.   Yes...starting with the restrictions makes sense, though sometimes ignoring the restriction and then invoking symmetry (as in the posted solution from @BarryCipra) works beautifully.  But it's really hard to generalize.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. This is a very new area of mathematics for me, so I really appreciate having some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't worry whether the number is even or odd, just that it's bigger than $600$, then the count is $2\cdot5\cdot4=40$, since the first digit must be $6$ or $7$ and the other two can be anything (that's not already been used).  Since there are the same number of even and odd digits (three of each), and also the same number available for the lead digit (one of each), the result is symmetric between even and odd, so the number of each is $40/2=20$.

Remark: This only works as nicely as it does because of the symmetry (i.e., equality) in the counts of even and odd digits. If you were using the digits $1$ to $7$, say, or $2$ to $8$ it wouldn't work, and you'd have to go with something case-based.

Comment: Thank you. So, if there were 3 possible lead digits or, say, 3 available odds and 4 available evens, would it be possible to approach this problem in the same way and divide by something else at the end?

Comment: @T.Biscuit, no. At least I don't think so. I've added a remark to clarify.

Comment: Ok. And just to clarify, we're only paying attention to the symmetry of lead digits because one is even and one is odd (therefore affecting the pool of available evens/odds), correct?

Comment: @T.Biscuit, no, there is also the symmetry in the *total* number of even and odd digits.

Comment: Correction: I meant to ask is that the only reason we look at the symmetry of the lead digits? I know we want to look at the total as well.

Comment: @T.Biscuit, ah, in that case Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question:

> How many ways to build a $3$-digit odd number (no repetition)

We have $5$ odd numbers, namely, $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ and we also have $3$ spots where we could put the numbers. __ __ __ In the first one we could place any of the 5 numbers that we have, then $4$ is left and finally $3$ so it would be $5*4*3 = 5P3 = 60$ odd numbers.

If repetition is allowed, it would be $5^3$

That could be done in $5\choose3$ to choose where we will place them and then multiply by 3$!$ to arrange them among themselves ways which would give 1$0*6 = 60$ again. Depends on if the order is important or not.

> How many $3$-digit odd numbers greater than $600$ can be created using the
>   digits $2,3,4,5,6,$ and $7$? Repetition of digits is not allowed.

If we are only to use odd numbers, and we want the number to be greater than 600, then we should start by $6$, or $7$ which would be $2$ possibilities, then we have 4 remaining digits out of the 5, let's choose now any of the 5 digits, and then 4 would be left so it would give $2*5*4 = 40$ and don't forget about the leading digits which would divide the answer by 2.